Cartan subspace
We know that in the classification of Cartan for Symmetric spaces (spaces admitting an involution), Cartan subalgebras and Cartan subspaces (residing in the tangent space of the space) play an essential role.
I was wondering if a similar concept exists for 3-symmetric spaces (spaces equipped with an order-3 automorphism). Specifically, is there an analogue of Cartan subspaces in the context of 3-symmetric spaces?
Could you please suggest some relevant references, both recent and older, on this topic?
Regards,

Worth noting that 3-symmetric spaces are a type of reductive homogeneous space so we have a reductive decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{m}$ and so we have a natural definition of Cartan subspace as an abelian (maybe we have to insist upon toral now) subalgebra of $\mathfrak{m}$. I can't find anywhere in the literature that actually does this annoyingly as I would also like an answer to this in the more general reductive case. Certainly the classification of 3-symmetric spaces doesn't use this.

@Callum Thanks. I know that the main classification of 3-symmetric spaces is the sequence of  work of Grey starting with :HOMOGENEOUS SPACES DEFINED BY LIE GROUP AUTOMORPHISMS. I. I am not sure if they use concept of Cartan subspaces instead of Cartan subalgebras residing in $\mathfrak{h}$.
